# login to Kubuntu 18.04 destroys desktop

Tags: kde, plasma

after login, desktop symbols are at wrong locations, 
too big and alphabetically sorted instead 
of the configured locations.
the taskbar is missing.
the desktop has the wrong wallpaper 
("Next von KDE Visual Design Group" instead of 
"Elarun von Nuno Pinheiro")

problem was introduced through regular updates
and occurs in 50% of login cases.

circumvention: kquitapp plasmashell /  plasmashell & disown.

then the desktop is back again and correct.
remark: we don't have to delete or restore datasets 
plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc,
plasmarc or plasmashellrc.

a cloned system (dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb) in a Thinkpad 
T61p (64 Bit) does not have the problem.

grub content:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 nopti nospectre_v1 nospectre_v2 
  l1tf=off nospec_store_bypass_disable noplymouth"

machine having problem is a Thinpad T60 (32 Bit).
system is (cf. "KDE Infozentrum"):
Kubuntu 18.04 (last update 14.08.2019)
KDE Plasma version 5.12.8
KDE Framwork version 5.44.0
Qt version 5.9.5 
Kernelversion 4.15.0.55-generic
32 bit system
hardware: 2 x intel cpu T2500 @ 2.00 Ghz 
memory: 2,0 GB

we did intensive research and log studies, but
no solution was found.

Comment: yeah, checked it, doesn't change anything

Comment: problem has been solved.

Comment: problem has been solved through installation of a new bios 
battery (cr 2032) for thinkpad t60. 

would be interesting to find out, how this could generate
software problems after booting (i.e. launching sddm/desktop)